# Replicate the Load runner scenario in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, loadrunner

I want to recreate the loadrunner scenario in Jmeter using ultimate thread group But iam Lost .

This is the Load runner scenario

[image: Load runner Scenario]

Attached the schedule Graph below

[image: Schedule Graph]

Below is the formation of ultimate thread group jmeter scenario that i tried which did not work (it is incomplete iam not able to complete it )

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't understand what's written in plain English you should invest some time into learning this language, i.e. https://www.duolingo.com/ is a good option
2. If you don't understand how to implement what's written in English in Ultimate Thread Group you should invest some time to get familiarized with the Ultimate Thread Group documentation and supporting materials:

   - [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/)
   - [Configure an Ultimate Thread Group Scenario](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000291018-Configure-an-Ultimate-Thread-Group-Scenario)
3. If you need someone to do you job for you this is not a right place, consider freelancer marketplaces like [fiverr](https://www.fiverr.com/) or [upwork](https://www.upwork.com/)
4. The equivalent Ultimate Thread Group configuration would be  something like:

   [image]